# how to extract data using jtidy and xpath

Tags: xpath, jtidy

i have to extract d company name and face value from
    http://money.rediff.com/companies/20-microns-ltd/15110088

i noticed that this task could be accomplished using xpath api.
since this is an html page, i am using jtidy parser.

this is the xpath for the face value which i have to extract.

```
/html/body/div[4]/div[6]/div[9]/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]
```

This is my code

```java
URL oracle = new URL("http://money.rediff.com/companies/20-microns-ltd/15110088");
URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
InputStream is = yc.getInputStream();
is = oracle.openStream();
Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
tidy.setQuiet(true);
tidy.setShowWarnings(false);
Document tidyDOM = tidy.parseDOM(is, null);
XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xPath = xPathFactory.newXPath();
String expression = "/html";
XPathExpression xPathExpression = xPath.compile(expression);
Object result = xPathExpression.evaluate(tidyDOM,XPathConstants.NODESET);
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

please guide me further, because, i cannot find a right solution for the above

Answer (score 3):

Try not to use "full" xpaths.

```
//div[@id='leftcontainer']//div[9]//table//tr[4]/td[2]
```

is better than

```
/html/body/.../.../.../.../.../...
```

Most HTML pages are not valid or even well-formed.  So the DOM structure may change when processed by "real-world HTML parsers".  For example, a `<tbody>` may be inserted under `<table>` if there isn't one.  Things are worse when different HTML parsers generate different DOM trees so one XPath may be valid for one parser, but not the other.  I would rather use "wildcards" like `table//tr[4]` instead of `table/tbody/tr[4]` or `table/tr[4]` so that I can forget about `<tbody>`.  Such expressions are more robust when used against the messy real-world HTML pages.

You can use Firepath, a plugin for Firebug which is then a plugin for Firefox, to debug XPath expressions.

p.s. You can try my JHQL (http://github.com/wks/jhql) project for exactly this task.  You will like it if you have more pages to extract data from.

Comment: i will follow your guidelines and post the results here.
meanwhile, what do you suggest about the given code ?

Comment: Some objects in your code can be shared.  Compiling XPath is expensive.  If the page is supposed to be monitored continuously, you can make the XPath a static field.  `Tidy` is not thread-safe (see this: [link](http://markmail.org/message/4uf4daiynx545s6i) ), but HtmlCleaner claimed to be safe (see [link](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/javause.php) ). Then a thread-safe HTML parser can also be shared.

Comment: And try Jaxen. According to my experience it is much faster than the XPath implementation that came with Java.