# Simplest way to extract information (parsing) from HTML in Java

Tags: java, html, xml-parsing

I've read a lot of questions on stackoverflow regarding html parsing.
I've learned that, when possible, we should avoid regex and use a parser instead.
I know that there are a lot of Html/Xml parser but I don't know how to use them properly.

Consider this html, parsed through jTidy. I've got a Document object created by jTidy of this code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Header content -->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="id1"> ... </div>
        <div id="id2"> ... </div>
        <div id="mainContent">
            <div id="section 1">
                <div id="subSection">
                    <!-- Interested part -->
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="success">
                            <td class="fileName"><span>File One</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="fail">
                            <td class="fileName"><span>File Two</span></td>
                        </tr>                        
                        <tr class="success">
                            <td class="fileName"><span>File Three</span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Now, I would like to map (in a Map :D ) each filename with its class (success/fail).
I can do it with DOM, but I should create a NodeList and for each Element create a new nodelist (lots of memory and boring). There are alternatives like Sax, Xerces etc etc. but I don't know advantages/disadvantages of them.

What is the simplest (and fastest) way to extract those information from the "jTyded" html above?

Comment: Use an XPath

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049150/how-to-extract-data-using-jtidy-and-xpath

Comment: I've read about XPath but the problem is that i should:
1) create a pattern for filenames
2) create a pattern for classes
3) associate class/filename
It's not very simple

Comment: How about HtmlUnit: http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Angelo I don't understand why it isn't simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - you forgot to add `<table>` tag.

You can very easy parse you code with **Jsoup**

Here is an example:

```
//  String html =" ...here goes your html code... ";
// Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
// Or from file:
    File input = new File("com.htm");
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8");
    Elements trs = doc.select("tr"); //select all "tr" elements from document
    for(Element tr:trs){
        //Getting the class string form tr element
        System.out.println("The file class is: " + tr.attr("class") 
       //getting the filename string that holds inside td element
         + " The filamee is: "  + tr.select("td").text());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. <table> was ignored because of too much indentation. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best approach would be to use XSLT+XPath (as Greg suggested in comment) in order to produce input for [unmarshaller](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html).

So the entire flow looks like below:
HTML->[jTidy purifying]->XHTL->[XSLT transformation]->string data representation->[JAXB unmarshaller]->Java object(s).

If you don't want to have objects produced, use only XPath as described in this thread: [How to read XML using XPath in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java)